# Displaying data frame in r markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to have table in 'one line' instead of dividing it. In the second picture is what I get and in the first picture is what I want to get. Thanks for your help.
1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwfZ5.png
2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUJ2.png

my code

````
title: "Bundesliga - raport"
author: "aa aak"
date: "3 stycznia 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=12, fig.height=8, fig.path='Figs/',
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
library(vcd)
```

## Bundesliga

a

```{r echo=FALSE}
head(Bundesliga)
```
````

Comment: please post your code; you have to show that you've made an effort

Comment: What about `kable(Bundesliga)`. This function is part of `knitr` package

Comment: @PoGibas good suggestion. you should check this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `width` option.  This works on your example:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
options(width = 100)
head(Bundesliga)
```
````